# How to move to next page when reach the end of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I was trying to achieve this concept that the designer required me to do but unfortunately, I haven't had luck doing the exact thing.

What I want to achieve is when the user scrolls and detect the end of its text it will move to another page or div.
Each `div` has fixed height so the text that overflows with the `div` should be scrolling.

[Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqlxra03y15f3hs/3%20pages.mov?dl=0)

Comment: So what is the specific problem? Have you tried anything? ...Using an event listener for the `scroll` event or using `window.location` for the redirect ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your code? No one is going to do your assignments here from scratch.